# Getting episode info from OMDb API

Tags: java, api, imdb

I'm using the awesome OMDb API in my app, and I wanted to be able to search for episode info using this API.

So far I've been able to search for movies / episodes but I couldn't find a way to search for a specific episode. (I guess I could do this using the episode's IMDB id, but to find that I need to search OMDb, which I don't know how)

Does anyone know of a way to perform this task?

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution for this?

Comment: It's an old one, but yeah :)

Comment: Cool. (Simple) Solution below. I had this other super-convoluted solution ready to go, but it looks like OMDb supports episode / title search now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OMDb API supports episode search ([as of 5/15/2015](http://www.omdbapi.com/)). In order to search for a specific episode of a show using Java, you'd want to do something like the following (the key params here are `episode` and `season`):

```
String url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/";
String charset = "UTF-8";
String title = "Game of Thrones";
String season = "5";
String episode "5";

String query = String.format("t=%s&season=%s&episode=%s", 
     URLEncoder.encode(title, charset), 
     URLEncoder.encode(season, charset),
     URLEncoder.encode(episode, charset),);

URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
// Do some stuff with the data
```

Take note that this method uses Java's URLConnection package. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), and read a super great tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests).

Comment: Cool! This really helps a lot. Much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, the correct query for getting the info is something like this: `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Game%20of%20Thrones&Season=1&Episode=1`

So you should modify your answer and change the "title" to "t" :)

Comment: good catch. thanks. glad this helped! (I wish I had it about 4 months ago)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to implement :)

Comment: @bfritz  Is there not any way to get episode details or list of episodes just by episode name? or do you need to have series title/id and season and episode number?  i would have thought something like http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=***&s=The Contest&type=episode&y=1992  or   http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=***&t=The Contest&type=episode&y=1992   might get a listing of episodes with that name